# PINARELLO F10 bottom bracket help

Tags: road-bike, bottom-bracket, compatibility

Need some help please.
Recently, I bought a used PINARELLO F10 frame set; it didn’t come with BB.
Here, I have been trying to not break my bank; my budget is pretty small after this expensive purchase.
The seller gave some information: BSA68 and I measured the inside diameter about 33mm. Can’t figure out the correct BB size.

Comment: A recent dogma i built used an italian thread bottom bracket. Check before putting in the wrong thing. That was the most recent Team Sky model but i forget the F number

Answer (score 3):

It's the most common type of threaded shell, sometimes called BSA. You'll sometimes also see it referred to as ISO (the same thing for all intents and purposes) or simply threaded. It's the threaded road shell that isn't Italian. All you have to do to confirm Italian vs BSA is measure the width of the bottom bracket shell from face to face. If it's a threaded shell and it's 70mm, it's Italian. If it's threaded and 68mm, BSA. (The 33mm you're getting is kind of a red herring either way because it doesn't correspond to either. The Italian thread is M36x24tpi and BSA is 1.375" (34.9mm)x24tpi.

What bottom bracket you need to buy is wholly dependent on what cranks you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Pinarello, like many Italian manufacturers, is likely to have an Italian threaded BB, *not* a BSA. I can't absolutely confirm this as I don't know what year F10 you have, but if you Google, you will see that it's generally known that Pinarello uses Italian thread. If it is Italian thread, the seller was misinformed. This is possible because Italian threaded BBs are relatively rare.

The diameter of the BB shell for a BSA BB is actually between 33.6 and 33.9mm. For Italian shells, the diameter is 35mm. The width of the BB shell is 68mm for BSA (road) and 70mm for Italian. Furthermore, the drive-side of a BSA shell is left-hand threaded, i.e. the threads run reverse to almost all the other threads on the bike. You should double check your measure of the internal diameter, and you can also measure the width. Plus you can see if the threads on either side run in the same direction (Italian) or if the drive-side is reversed.

Not all Italian bikes use Italian threading. My understanding is that many do. I was under the general impression that Pinarello has always had Italian threading, but I also don't follow Pinarello closely as a brand. Thus, you'd want to double check your measurements of the shell.